Some models are broken after export to .glb
I'm trying to export an a-frame scene with some 3D models on it, the export works but the resulting glb file is not correct
This is my a-frame scene:
<a-scene id="scene" embedded renderer="logarithmicDepthBuffer: true; antialias: true;" vr-mode-ui="enabled: false" gltf-model="dracoDecoderPath: https://www.gstatic.com/draco/v1/decoders/;" inspector keyboard-shortcuts screenshot device-orientation-permission-ui>
    <a-node class="no-export" id="sceneLoader"></a-node>
    <a-entity class="no-export" id="mainPlane">
        <a-entity class="no-export" id="cr_animation"></a-entity>
        <a-entity class="no-export clickable" cursor-listener geometry="primitive: plane" position="1 0 0" scale="0.9 0.9 0.9" rotation="-90 0 0" material="color: #FFFFFFB5; opacity: 0.8; transparent: true"></a-entity>
        <a-entity class="no-export clickable" cursor-listener geometry="primitive: plane" position="0 0 0" scale="0.9 0.9 0.9" rotation="-90 0 0" material="color: #FFFFFFB5; opacity: 0.8; transparent: true"></a-entity>
        <a-entity class="no-export clickable" cursor-listener geometry="primitive: plane" position="-1 0 0" scale="0.9 0.9 0.9" rotation="-90 0 0" material="color: #FFFFFFB5; opacity: 0.8; transparent: true"></a-entity>
        <a-entity class="no-export clickable" cursor-listener geometry="primitive: plane" position="1 0 -1" scale="0.9 0.9 0.9" rotation="-90 0 0" material="color: #FFFFFFB5; opacity: 0.8; transparent: true"></a-entity>
        <a-entity class="no-export clickable" cursor-listener geometry="primitive: plane" position="0 0 -1" scale="0.9 0.9 0.9" rotation="-90 0 0" material="color: #FFFFFFB5; opacity: 0.8; transparent: true"></a-entity>
        <a-entity class="no-export clickable" cursor-listener geometry="primitive: plane" position="-1 0 -1" scale="0.9 0.9 0.9" rotation="-90 0 0" material="color: #FFFFFFB5; opacity: 0.8; transparent: true"></a-entity>
        <a-entity class="no-export clickable" cursor-listener geometry="primitive: plane" position="1 0 -2" scale="0.9 0.9 0.9" rotation="-90 0 0" material="color: #FFFFFFB5; opacity: 0.8; transparent: true"></a-entity>
        <a-entity class="no-export clickable" cursor-listener geometry="primitive: plane" position="0 0 -2" scale="0.9 0.9 0.9" rotation="-90 0 0" material="color: #FFFFFFB5; opacity: 0.8; transparent: true"></a-entity>
        <a-entity class="no-export clickable" cursor-listener geometry="primitive: plane" position="-1 0 -2" scale="0.9 0.9 0.9" rotation="-90 0 0" material="color: #FFFFFFB5; opacity: 0.8; transparent: true"></a-entity>
        <a-entity class="no-export" id="capsulemodel4365">
            <a-entity class="export" id="model4365" gltf-model="https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev-cityar-storage/assets/web-app-object/GingerBread_Man_new2_2023-12-02-001020_jfen.glb" shadow="cast: true;" animation-mixer=""></a-entity>
        </a-entity>
        <a-entity class="no-export" id="capsulemodel4377">
            <a-entity class="export" id="model4377" gltf-model="https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev-cityar-storage/assets/web-app-object/cr_meerkat_model_2023-06-15-141803_iqyy.glb" shadow="cast: true;" animation-mixer=""></a-entity>
        </a-entity>
    </a-entity>
    <a-light class="no-export" id="dirLight" light="castShadow: true; shadowRadius: 3" type="directional" intensity="0.25" position="0.15 6 -1"></a-light>
    <a-light class="no-export" light="castShadow: false;" type="directional" intensity="0.75" position="-3 3 5"></a-light>
    <a-light class="no-export" light="castShadow: false;" type="directional" intensity="0.75" position="3 3 5"></a-light>
    <a-light class="no-export" light="castShadow: false;" type="directional" intensity="0.25" position="-3 3 -5"></a-light>
    <a-light class="no-export" light="castShadow: false;" type="directional" intensity="0.25" position="3 3 -5"></a-light>
    <a-entity class="no-export" camera="fov: 85" position="0 2.25 2" rotation="-15 0 0" look-controls="enabled: false">
        <a-entity class="no-export" cursor="rayOrigin: mouse;" raycaster="objects: .clickable;"></a-entity>
    </a-entity>
</a-scene>

This is how the scene looks:

This is the export code
<script type="module">

import { GLTFExporter } from 'https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/exporters/GLTFExporter.js';

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    const btn = document.createElement('button');
    btn.textContent = 'Download .glb';
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
    btn.onclick = download;

    function download() {
        const scene = document.getElementById("scene").object3D;
        console.log("Scene before export:", scene);

        const objectsToExport = [];
        scene.traverse(child => {
            console.log("child name:", child.name, child.type);
            if (child.el && child.el.classList && !child.el.classList.contains('no-export') ) {
                console.log("child name:", child.name);
                console.log("child:", child);
                const mesh = child.el.object3DMap.mesh;
                let capsuleModel = child;
                const capsule = document.getElementById('capsule' + child.el.id);
                if(capsule){
                    capsuleModel = capsule.object3D;
                }
                if (mesh) {
                    mesh.position.copy(capsuleModel.position);
                    mesh.rotation.copy(child.rotation);
                    mesh.scale.copy(child.scale);
                    mesh.updateMatrix();
                    objectsToExport.push(mesh);
                } else {
                    console.warn("Mesh not found for child:", child);
                }
            } else {
                console.log("Skipping non-exportable child:", child);
            }
        });

        console.log("Objects to export:", objectsToExport);
        const originalChildren = scene.children.slice();
        scene.children = objectsToExport;
        console.log("Scene after setting export objects:", scene.children);

        const exporter = new GLTFExporter();
        exporter.parse(scene, result => {
            console.log("Export successful. Restoring original scene children.");
            saveArrayBuffer(result, 'scene.glb');
            scene.children = originalChildren;
            console.log("Scene restored to original children:", scene.children);
        }, error => {
            console.error('An error happened during export:', error);
            scene.children = originalChildren;
            console.log("Scene restored to original children after error:", scene.children);
        }, { binary: true });
    }

    function saveArrayBuffer(buffer, filename) {
        save(new Blob([buffer], { type: 'application/octet-stream' }), filename);
    }

    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(link);

    function save(blob, filename) {
        link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.download = filename;
        link.click();
    }});
</script>

This is the result after the export:

It kind of works but there arethose problems that I can't find. Any ideas?
I'm trying to export the scene the export works but the models are broken.

what is not right?

you can check the result image the models are no correct, the export works its just that the result is not what it should be
